# Excel date format issue

Tags: excel, date, format

I am trying to enter the dates in `mm/dd/yy` format(selecting the cell format as general) in two cells
but the issue is the 2nd cell is automatically changed to date format

[image]

Comment: Try changing the number format of that column to `Text` first. Although, if you're to operate on these dates later, I would suggest keeping the date format (you can always customize it via `More Number Formats...` > `Date` / `Custom`).

Answer (score 1):

Excel automatically converts entries to a serialised date value when:
a)  the cell number format is General or any Date format; and
b)  you Enter any value that can be interpreted as (aka coerced to) a date.

Excel also automatically changes the number format of a cell to a Date format when:
a)  the cell number format is General ; and
b)  you Enter a value that can be interpreted as (aka coerced to) a date.

'Interpreted as' includes entries such as:
o  '1/1' or '1-1' will both be converted 1 January in the current year
o  24/1 or 1/24 will be converted to 24 January in the current year (regardless of local settings)
o  1/1/21 will be converted 1 January in 2021

These features can't be disabled. So all you can do is work with them:
o Conversion to serialized date values is crucial (else entering dates would be a really hard).
o Changing number formats is avoided by having cells with dates formatted as  dates in the first place.

As an aside: the above also applies to time values and time formats (though 'Interpreted as' changes to entries like N: or N:N or NN:NN, etc).